# Why I can't get the text for this element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to test some search function in a webpage. and if no result return, the page shows text "**no result**". I can see the text, but my test code can't get the value.

I tried

```
document.querySelector("div[class='bold ng-binding']").text;
document.querySelector("div[class='bold ng-binding']").innerHTML;
document.querySelector("div[class='bold ng-binding']").value;
```

Nothing works. it always returns "None".

The Element looks like this:

`<div ng-show="expanded && !show" class="bold ng-binding">No Result</div>`

Comment: It's not possible to get `None` as a value for two of those, `.text` and `.value` you would get a `undefined` value as `div` elements do not have those properties (unless you set them).

Comment: I know.  but what should I do if I want to get the "No result"?

Comment: what does this have to do with robotframework? None of the code in your question is related to robotframework.

Comment: robot framework can call Execute Javascript, right?  I will use robot framework to call this code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it specific to get text of page.

What is prefer for test is:

I will check whether 'No Result' text is shown for search.

Following possible ways:

1. `Page Should Contain    No Result`

   # This verifies No Result text is present in page (not preferred)

Or

2. `Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://div[text()='No Result']`

   #This verifies element is present - if not then keyword will fail

Above answers are my opinions.